# Android RecyclerView Gravity issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I am using `DrawerLayout` to show `Navigation Drawer`, in that A `NavigationView`, the `xml` code is :

**MyDrawerLayout.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/layout_navigation_list" />

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

**layout_navigation_list.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@color/white"
 android:orientation="vertical">

   <include
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    layout="@layout/nav_header_dash_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:gravity="top" />

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerNav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:foregroundGravity="bottom" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: ScreenImage]

In the `RecyclerView` i have only 3 items to be shown, and they are aligning on the top of the `RecyclerView` layout which is i don't want. Hence my question here is , how to send those items to the bottom of the `RecyclerView` (just like shown in the image).

Answer (score 1):

Set `match_parent` instead `wrap_content` field `layout_height` in `relativeLayout` :

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@color/white"
 android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a `ConstraintLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        layout="@layout/nav_header_dash_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:gravity="top" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerNav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to `MATCH_PARENT` height instead of `WRAP_CONTENT` in root relative layout in file `layout_navigation_list.xml`. So it looks like,

```
<RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/white"
   android:orientation="vertical">
 ...
 ...
 ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Notes:** Gravity won't work with relative layouts.